# Result with assumptions contradicts previous result

Tags: special-functions, complex, series-expansion, assumptions

Without assuming anything on the argument of the complex number inside the Gamma function

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals}, Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b], {x, ∞, 0}]]]]
```

produces

[image]

However, adding that the argument of the Gamma function can't be just a negative real number leads to

```
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, Arg[a x + b] < π}, 
  Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b], {x, ∞, 0}]]]]
```

with result

```
0
```

What is going on here?

**UPDATE** Also I should probably mention that both [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11) and the [Wolfram functions website](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/02/) suggest that the leading order term in this expansion should be

```
E^(-b - a*x)*Sqrt[2*Pi]*(b + a*x)^(-1/2 + b + a*x)
```

which is different than any of the answers that Mathematica gives.

Comment: Try {x, \[Infinity], 1} instead of  {x, \[Infinity], 0}  in your second code.

Comment: This would include higher order terms plus it produces a different answer by a factor of `Sqrt[2\[Pi]]x^(-1/2+b)`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Somos I am not trying to solve any particular problem. I ask Mathematica to do some series and it gives me an answer that has two options depending on the assumptions on the variables involved. I then reattempt the calculation, providing one set of assumptions of those two that Mathematica gave me earlier and expect to get the answer corresponsing to that assumption, but I don't. There is certainly something going wrong here, right?

Comment: If what you state is the case, then you have discovered just one instance of where Mathematica does not produce results that you expected. It is not a bug but a feature. If you had a real problem to solve, then it would be a more serious situation. Yes, certainly, your assumptions about how Mathematica works are very likely to be wrong. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Somos If I wanted to expand `Gamma[ax+b]` for large x and used the first line of code - I get two **non-zero** options. Then let us say that I realise that in my problem `ax+b` does have an argument that is less than pi and look at what Mathematica has given me and tell myself "It is the first option that applies to me, so I pick this".

Comment: @Somos However, I could've also realised from the very beginning, before any lines of code, that `ax+b` has argument less than pi and provide this as an assumption, as in the second line of code, and then a get **zero** as an answer. In both situations I am asking for exactly the same thing, but I get a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
ex = Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals, Arg[a x + b] < Pi}, 
  Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b]/Sqrt[2 Pi], {x, Infinity, 0}]]]];
ex // InputForm
```

which returns the result in version 10.2

```
(a^(-1/2 + b + a*x)*(x^(-1))^(1/2 - b - a*x))/E^(a*x)
```

**but** in the latest version returns

```
a^(-1/2 + b + a*x)*E^((1 - 6*b + 6*b^2 - 12*a^2*x^2)/(12*a*x))*x^(-1/2 + b + a*x)
```

Note that the answer has changed between versions so it is automatically suspect. Also note carefully that the real difference from your input here is that the `Gamma[a x + b]` is divided by `Sqrt[2 Pi]`. If that is removed, then the result is `0`. This does not make sense mathematically, but it is probably an obscure bug. Thanks for noticing it.

However, if you use more terms for the `Series[]` then things get much stranger. The expression is `Exp[]` and the power series is in the exponential. What I mean is that the following code

```
ex = Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals, Arg[a x + b] < Pi}, Sqrt[2 Pi]
   Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b]/Sqrt[2 Pi], {x, Infinity, 2}]]]];
ex[[2]] // InputForm
```

in the latest version returns the result

```
E^(-(b + 2*b^3 + 6*a*b*x - 3*b^2*(1 + 2*a*x) + a*x*(-1 + 12*a^2*x^2))/(12*a^2*x^2))
```

but you get a different result if you don't multiply and divide by `Sqrt[2 Pi]`. Clearly, something strange is going on here.

My advice to you would be to use something like

```
ex = Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals},
   Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[x], {x, Infinity, 3}]]]] /. x -> a x + b;
ex // InputForm
```

which returns the result

```
(E^(-b - a*x)*Sqrt[Pi/2]*(b + a*x)^(-5/2 + b = a*x)*(1+ 24*(b + a*x) + 288*(b+ a*x)^2)/144
```

Comment: Which Mathematica version are you using, as I am with 11.3 and I get different things from you. Specifically, the first line of code you have shown returns `a^(-1/2 + b + a*x)*E^((1 - 6*b + 6*b^2 - 12*a^2*x^2)/(12*a*x))*x^(-1/2 + b + a*x)` for me. And the second one gives completely different stuff 
`E^(-(1 - 30*b^4 - 30*a^2*x^2 + 360*a^4*x^4 + 60*b^3*(1 + a*x) + 30*a*b*x*(1 + 6*a*x) - 30*b^2*(1 + 3*a*x + 6*a^2*x^2))/(360*a^3*x^3))`

Comment: Also, check the update to my original post.

Comment: I agree with what you have suggested, with the exception that in this case you are implicitly assuming that `a` and `b` are real, by demanding that `x` in `Gamma[x]` is real and then doing a replacement after the series expansion. The amusing thing is that in this situation all the factors are correct, even the `Sqrt[Pi/2]`.
So what is the conclusion from all this? There is a subtle bug going on here? How is this to be reported?

Comment: You have to distinguish between what is mathematically meaningul and what Mathematica outputs. Mathematica and **al**l other computer programs do not understand mathematics. Hopefully, you **do** know mathematics and can judge the validity of the results produced and adjust accordingly. You can report this as strange and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way it should be fine

```
Refine[Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b], {x, \[Infinity], 0}]]], 
 Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals}]


Refine[Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b], {x, \[Infinity], 0}]]], 
 Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, Arg[a x + b] < \[Pi]}]
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: So, does that mean that I should be using `Refine` from now on with Assumptions as an option?
Also, check the update to my original post.

Comment: I don't think you even need the Refine: Simplify[Normal[Series[Gamma[a x + b], {x, \[Infinity], 0}]], Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, Arg[a x + b] < \[Pi]}] gives the expected answer. This suggests that the problem is with placing the Assumptions first, rather than later in the expression.

Comment: I see. Shall this be reported somehow?